# Workflow increase version

Tags: workflow, email, version

I have a simple email alert workflow like below:

**If Current Item:Version = 1.0 
then Pause for 0 days,0 hours,1 minutes
then Email New document alert.
Else 
then Pause for 0 days,0 hours,1 minutes
Send Modified document Email alert. 
go to end of workflow.**

If I have versioning Settings turned on with Require documents  to be checked out before they can be edited it seems to work fine.  If I remove the Required documents to be checked out then it seems to increase the versions.

So for example if I add a new document it starts off as version 1.0, but when the workflow runs it changes to version 2.0.
Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that workflow is updating some properties of the file/item. Everytime that WF does that it increases file's version. It's common behaviour.